# Codeigniter IonAuth Library - redirect after a group member logins

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, verification

I have just used and installed IonAuth on my Codeigniter app.

I have setup 3 user groups..

Admin
Members
Media Partners

Would it be possible to redirect each user group to their unique dashboard area rather than the home page?

e.g.

admins log in and are redirected to => `/admin/dashboard/`
members log in and are redirected to => `/users/dashboard/`
media partners log in and are redirected to => `/media-info/dashboard/`

How would I go about this in my auth controller?

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 1):

In your login function check the group and redirect accordingly.

```
function login () 
{
    //Login code
    ...
    //Login Successful
    $user = $this->ion_auth->get_user(); 

    switch ($user->group)
    {
        case ('admin'):
            redirect(site_url('admin/dashboard'), 'refresh');
        break;
        case ('user'):
            redirect(site_url('users/dashboard'), 'refresh');
        break;
        case ('media'):
            redirect(site_url('media-info/dashboard'), 'refresh');
        break;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: That works, but why do you have brackets around your case string? No need :) Also, why set refresh? No need to do that either.

Comment: 'refresh' is the syntax used by ion auth, so if nothing else it is consistent with the topic. Additionally, according to the CI docs, the default redirect method of 'location' can sometimes be a problem on Windows servers, so in theory I suppose the code is more portable this way, if you get stuck on one of those servers.

Answer (score 0):

here is mine, if someone looking for using function if

```
function index()
{
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        // redirect them to the login page
        redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
    }
    else
    {
    if ($this->ion_auth->in_group('admin'))
    {
        echo "<h1>here is admin</h1>";
    }   
    else if ($this->ion_auth->in_group('user'))
    {
        echo "<h1>here is user</h1>";
    }
    else if ($this->ion_auth->in_group('media'))
    {
        echo "<h1>here is media</h1>";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "nothing happen"
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone out there,

NOte : Make sure group your group same like  above